# How to get a float number in input GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python trying to make a simple converter app, but my problem is i can't figure out how to solve the km to m. If i figure this out I can figure out the rest. Thanks in advance! Here's my code

```
import tkinter from tkinter import ttk

window=tkinter.Tk() 
window.title("Conversion Unit")

labelOne=ttk.Label(window, text='Enter Value') 
labelOne.grid(row=0, column=0) 
to_be_converted=ttk.Combobox(
    values=('mm', 'cm', 'inches', 'feet', 'yards', 'meter', 'km', 'miles'),
    width=10
).grid(row=0, column=2)

labelTwo=ttk.Label(window, text="Equivalent to") 
labelTwo.grid(row=1, column=1) 
converted=ttk.Combobox(
    values=('mm', 'cm', 'inches', 'feet', 'yards', 'meter', 'km', 'miles'),
    width=10
).grid(row=1, column=2)

userName=tkinter.DoubleVar()

userEntry=ttk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=userName)
userEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

def convert():
    if to_be_converted.get=='km' and converted.get=='m':
        labelTwo.configure(text='Value is equivalent to:' + userName.get() * 1000) 
        btn=ttk.Button(window, text='Convert!', command=convert) 
        btn.grid(row=0, column=4)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post your correct code?  I was sort of edited, but not really.  If you have to, you can enclose it in <pre> tags (e.g. `<pre>your code</pre>`) and someone will come along and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version, there are a few changes:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

UNITS = ('mm', 'cm', 'inches','feet', 'yards', 'meter', 'km', 'miles')

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Conversion Unit")

labelOne = ttk.Label(window,text='Enter Value')
labelOne.grid(row=0,column=0)
to_be_converted = ttk.Combobox(values=UNITS, width=10)
to_be_converted.grid(row=0, column=2)

labelTwo = ttk.Label(window, text="Equivalent to")
labelTwo.grid(row=1,column=1)
converted = ttk.Combobox(values=UNITS, width=10)
converted.grid(row=1, column=2)

userName = tkinter.DoubleVar()
userEntry = ttk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable = userName)
userEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

def convert():
    if to_be_converted.get() == 'km' and converted.get() == 'meter':
        labelTwo.configure(text='Value is equivalent to:' + str(userName.get()*1000))

btn = ttk.Button(window, text='Convert!', command=convert)
btn.grid(row=0, column=4)

window.mainloop()
```

**.grid() returns None**

So this line:

```
to_be_converted = ttk.Combobox(values=UNITS, width=10).grid(row=0, column=2 )
```

Has to be:

```
to_be_converted = ttk.Combobox(values=UNITS, width=10)
to_be_converted.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

(same with `converted`)

**`.get` is a bound method, not an attribute**

So this line:

```
if to_be_converted.get == 'km' and converted.get == 'meter':
```

has to be:

```
if to_be_converted.get() == 'km' and converted.get() == 'meter':
```

(and 'm' has to be replaced with 'meter' -- or `UNITS` has to have 'm', not 'meter').

**Can't concatenate string with float**

So this line:

```
labelTwo.configure(text='Value is equivalent to:' + userName.get()*1000)
```

Has to be, for example:

```
labelTwo.configure(text='Value is equivalent to:' + str(userName.get()*1000))
```